# Why isn't my mysql query seeing this one combination of two variables but sees the rest?

Tags: coldfusion

I wrote a script that takes date entries and for some reason whenever I specify just a starting date with a blank end date the query never picks it up. Here's what I wrote.

```
<cfquery name="stec_mysql_loan_tracking_qry" result="meta_tracking" datasource="STLinux1MySQL">
    Select
        tslo.created,
        tslo.created_by,
        tslo.last_modified,
        tslo.last_modified_by,
        tslo.active,
        tslo.is_manager,
        tslo.pick_userid,
        tslo.customer_code,
        tslo.name,
        tst.user_ip as ip,
        tsl.loan_identifier,
        tst.command,
        tsl.tax_search_loan_id as id
    From
        tax_search_loan_officers tslo Left Join
        tax_search_loans tsl On tsl.tax_search_loan_officer_id =
        tslo.tax_search_loan_officer_id Left Join
        tax_search_track tst On tst.pick_userid = tslo.pick_userid
    Where
        tslo.customer_code In (<cfqueryparam value="#tw_custcodes#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="yes">)
        <cfif IsDefined('url.active')>
            <cfif url.active neq "">
                AND
                tslo.active = <cfqueryparam value="#Trim(url.active)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="yes">
            </cfif>
        </cfif>

        <cfif IsDefined('url.is_managed')>
            <cfif url.is_managed neq "">
                AND
                tslo.is_manager = <cfqueryparam value="#Trim(url.is_managed)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="yes">
            </cfif>
        </cfif>

        <cfif IsDefined('url.start_end')>
            <cfif url.start_date neq "" and url.end_date eq "">
                AND
                <cfqueryparam value="#Trim(url.start_date)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"> <= DATE_FORMAT(tslo.last_modified, '%Y-%m-%d')
                AND
                DATE_FORMAT(tslo.last_modified, '%Y-%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')
            </cfif>
        </cfif>

        <cfif IsDefined('url.start_date')>
            <cfif url.end_date neq "" and url.start_date eq "">
                AND
                '2012-01-01' <= DATE_FORMAT(tslo.last_modified, '%Y-%m-%d')
                AND
                DATE_FORMAT(tslo.last_modified, '%Y-%m-%d') <= <cfqueryparam value="#Trim(url.end_date)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
            </cfif>
        </cfif>

        <cfif isDefined('url.start_date')>
            <cfif (url.start_date neq "") and (url.end_date neq "")>
                AND
                <cfqueryparam value="#Trim(url.start_date)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"> <= DATE_FORMAT(tslo.last_modified, '%Y-%m-%d')
                AND
                DATE_FORMAT(tslo.last_modified, '%Y-%m-%d') <= <cfqueryparam value="#Trim(url.end_date)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
            </cfif>
        </cfif>
</cfquery>
```

And here is what it sees if `url.end_date = ""` but `url.start_date = a value`:

```
Select
  tslo.created,
  tslo.created_by,
  tslo.last_modified,
  tslo.last_modified_by,
  tslo.active,
  tslo.is_manager,
  tslo.pick_userid,
  tslo.customer_code,
  tslo.name,
  tst.user_ip as ip,
  tsl.loan_identifier,
  tst.command,
  tsl.tax_search_loan_id as id
From
  tax_search_loan_officers tslo Left Join
  tax_search_loans tsl On tsl.tax_search_loan_officer_id =
    tslo.tax_search_loan_officer_id Left Join
  tax_search_track tst On tst.pick_userid = tslo.pick_userid
Where
  tslo.customer_code In (?)
```

However, every other combination is fine. I've tried rewriting the `cfif` blocks but this structure is the only one that gets 2/3 while the rest fail.

Comment: can you explain the issue a little more? I'm not following

Comment: sorry for the obvious, but your sure you are sending URL variables with either a form action=get or a href tag, or are you using a FORM POST..... which is a "FORM.variablename"

Comment: Yeah, the logic is very hard to follow ... can you elaborate? It looks like you have three date variables: `url.start_date`, `url.end_date` and `url.start_end`. What is `url.start_end` - is it a typo?  As an aside, you might want to set defaults values for the variables so you could eliminate some of the cfif conditions. Then work on simplifying the rest of the logic, because it seems more complex than is necessary ...

Comment: I agree with @Leigh that the cfif IsDefined('url.start_end') looks wrong

Comment: Oh wow, I never caught the whole start_end thing. I'll change that. Good eye!

Comment: (Edit) Okay. BTW, any chance you have time to explain the "plain english" date logic too? :) I have a strong suspicion we could simplify the code and make the query more efficient to boot, by getting rid of the `DATE_FORMAT(ColumnName, ...)` (as it will prevent the db from effectively utilizing any indexes on that column.) No worries if you do not have time now.

Comment: Plus one vote from me because he displayed the sql being sent to the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From the comments ..)

> `<cfif IsDefined('url.start_end')>`

It looks like you have three date variables: `url.start_date`, `url.end_date` and `url.start_end`. What is `url.start_end` - is it a typo?

As an aside, you might want to set defaults values for the variables so you could eliminate some of the cfif conditions. Then work on simplifying the rest of the logic, because it seems more complex than is necessary ...  [Dan's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17052414/104223) contains some good suggestions. I strongly suspect you could simplify the code and make the query more efficient to boot by getting rid of the `DATE_FORMAT(ColumnName, '%Y-%m-%d')` statements, because they will prevent the database from properly utilizing indexes on the referenced column.

---

**Update:**

After taking a closer look, I think this is what the code is trying to accomplish:

- If *both* dates are present, filter on the given values
- If *only one* of the dates is present, apply a default for the missing date. Then filter on both values.
- If *neither* date is present, skip the filtering.

Something along these lines should mimic the behavior of current code. Note, it uses this type of comparison as a more index-friendly way of handling "time" issues:

```
    WHERE column >= {startDateAtMidnight}        
    AND   column <  {dayAfterEndDateAtMidnight}
```

**Example:**

```
<!--- default both to something that is NOT a valid date --->
<cfparam name="url.start_date" default="">
<cfparam name="url.end_date" default="">

<!--- 
    If at least ONE of the dates was supplied, apply 
    the desired defaults for missing values 
--->
<cfif isDate(url.start_date) || isDate(url.end_date)>
    <cfset url.start_date = isDate(url.start_date) ? url.start_date : "some default like 2012-01-01 here">
    <cfset url.end_date = isDate(url.end_date) ? url.end_date : now()>
</cfif>

<cfquery ....>
   SELECT ...
   FROM   ...
   WHERE  ...

   <!--- apply the filter when both dates are populated.  --->
   <cfif isDate(url.start_date) and isDate(url.end_date)>
        AND  tslo.last_modified >= <cfqueryparam value="#url.start_date#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
        AND  tslo.last_modified < <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1, url.end_date)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
   </cfif>
 </cfquery>
```

Comment: @VinceOmega - I was curious, so I took a stab at simplifying the logic. See updated response.

Comment: Yeah that's actually what the code was intended to do. This is much cleaner than what I had wrote before.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the cause, but you are mixing data types.  This:

```
and <cfqueryparam value="#Trim(url.start_date)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"> 
   <= DATE_FORMAT(tslo.last_modified, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

will have a date on the left hand side of your comparison operator and a string on the right.  Even if it runs without error, you might get unexpected results.  As a minimum, remove the date_format function from the right hand side.

Then we have this:

```
AND DATE_FORMAT(tslo.last_modified, '%Y-%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

at least it's comparing a string to a string, but it's inefficient.  In the overall scheme of things, maybe you want something like this:

```
and tslo.last_modified >=
 <cfqueryparam value="#Trim(url.start_date)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
and tslo.last_modified =< now()
```

Comment: I guess i'll remove the date format function if it is mixing the wrong types as you mentioned.